# Ratchet nav bars not displaying on additional pages, only on iOS 8

Tags: ios8, ratchet-2, ratchet-bootstrap

So I have noticed this issue on iOS 8 with both mobile safari and chrome. It was previously working, but for some reason now, my other pages are not putting the new pages nav bar on top of the original nav bar. It still works on desktop browsers and when emulating, even works on Android.

Initial Page:

```
<header class="bar bar-nav">
    <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
</header>
```

Second Page:

```
<div class="bar bar-nav">
    <a id="backButton" class="icon icon-left-nav pull-left"  
       onclick="window.history.back()" data-    
       ignore="push">Back</a>
    <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the tag being a div instead of header makes a  difference. Use chrome developer tools to see what happens on line 179 of [push.js](https://github.com/twbs/ratchet/blob/master/js/push.js)

Comment: I am having the same problem